# Publishing on Google play

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play

I have published my app from Alpha stage to Production,
everybody can now see it, but only alpha users are able to download it.

Each non alpha-user is getting the same error:

> the item you requested is not available for purchase

I should also mention the app is free, I don't have any in-app purchases options and my app was published successfully more than 15 hours ago.

I search similar questions, but most of the answer were in-app purchases related.

thanks,

Shuky

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to add your alpha users to a community either in via play store or in Google+ to give them access.

Comment: The problem is with users outside of the alpha group, as I said the app is public.

Comment: may be propagation time is long.just try the same after some hours